# "if" statement performs same action on every occurence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

In trying to switch the `turn` variable for every run of the `if` statement, I keep getting the same result. Every time, `turn` evaluates as `2`.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
  var turn = 2;

  if (turn == 1) {
    $(".box").on("click", function() {
      var $thisBox = $(this).children();
      $thisBox.addClass("x").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 1000);
    });
    turn = 2;
  } else if (turn == 2) {
    $(".box").on("click", function() {
      var $thisBox = $(this).children();
      $thisBox.addClass("o").animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 1000);
    });
    turn = 1;
  } else {
    document.write("Uh Oh");
  }
});
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `onClick` listener only once and check the value of the `turn` value inside the function called by the `onClick` event.

```js
$(function() {
  var turn = 2;
  
  $(".box").on("click", function() {
    if (turn === 1) {
      console.log('foo');
      turn = 2;
    } else if (turn === 2) {
      console.log('bar');
      turn = 1;
    } else {
     console.log("Uh Oh");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>Click me</div>
```

Comment: It still gives me the same result

Comment: The code is in a document ready event, it's going to run only once. The OP seems to need persistent data between page reloads.